# Bars get stacked in ngx vertical 2d bar chart

Tags: angular, ngx-charts

I am trying to add data to my ngx vertical 2d bar chart, but the bar in x axis is displayed in stacked format rather than displaying it in separate bar .

```
<ngx-charts-bar-vertical-2d>
   [results]="multi"
</ngx-charts-bar-vertical-2d>
```

my data

```
multi = {
    'name': 'sample1', 
    'series': [
      {
        'value': 100004096,
        'name': '20/06/2022'
      },
      {
        'value': 200004096, 
        'name': '21/06/2022'
      }
    ]
    },

  {
'name': 'sample2', 
'series': [
    {
        'value': 100004096, 
        'name': '20/06/2022'
    }, 
    {
        'value': 200004096, 
        'name': '21/06/2022'
    }
]},
{
'name': 'sample3', 
'series': [
    { 
        'value': 20501094656, 
        'name': '20/06/2022'
    }, 
    {
        'value': 20601094656, 
        'name': '21/06/2022'
    }
]}
];
```

Any mistake I am doing kindly help out in solving this issue

Comment: when i change showXAxis to false i could see two seperate bars in chart, how to see xaxis name and to do grouping